# What is the first element of Locale.getAvailableLocales?

Tags: java-8, locale

I'm testing `java.util.Locale` and I found that the first element of [Locale.getAvailableLocales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales--) is weird.

```
@Test
public void printFirstLocale() {
    final Locale firstLocale = Locale.getAvailableLocales()[0];
    System.out.println("first locale: " + firstLocale
                       + " " + firstLocale.hashCode());
}
```

Ant it just prints this.

```
first locale:  0
```

I got same results from OS X, Windows, and Xubuntu.

Comment: I'm out of votes, but [java.util.Locale has an empty first item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088874/java-util-locale-has-an-empty-first-item)

Comment: It's, shortly, [Locale.ROOT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Locale is an empty String. It is covered here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

> Returns the country/region code for this locale, which should either be the empty string, an uppercase ISO 3166 2-letter code, or a UN M.49 3-digit code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32323775/330457