# Locale.getDefault().getCountry() returning empty string

Tags: android, android-layout, locale

I am trying to get user language with country code, like `en-US`, `es-es`, but when i use `Locale.getDefault().getCountry()`, it returns empty string. Although it gives me correct language on `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()`

Comment: can you show the relevant code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Locale has an empty first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088874/java-util-locale-has-an-empty-first-item)