# Local.getDefault().getCountry() is not stable - Image Picker Android bug

Tags: java, android, locale, country-codes

In my application, this snippet:

```
Local.getDefault().getCountry()
```

At the very soon when application launches, it returns the correct value like FR/CA/GB/US.
But after a few moment it returns an empty string.
(in detail: we have a language param for our https request, we need to different fr_FR, fr_CA, en_US, en_CA...)

How to achieve the value of language correctly? (fr_FR, en_CA,...)

Some same domain but not identical topic:

[Locale.getDefault().getCountry() returning empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649594/locale-getdefault-getcountry-returning-empty-string) -> this question is not yet answered

[java.util.Locale has an empty first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088874/java-util-locale-has-an-empty-first-item)

Tested and found this unusual problem in reals devices: Android 6.0, 8.0, 9.0

Comment: Do you have code that would call `Locale.setDefault()` to replace the default locale? It might also be in a library you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is placed in a library we are using ( ImagePicker ). I shall post a issue on that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [laalto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101361/laalto)

I found the problem is in a library: Locale.setDefault() was called.
In my case, it was [ImagePicker](https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker/issues/283).